# In custom options multiple select

Tags: magento-1.9

Is there a way to add a pick 3 max in the multiple select form in the custom options page? It's got required but not any other validation.

Comment: Can you elaborate more. The question is not much clear

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to define a minimum other than 1, or any maximum in Magento.

From a UI perspective, you could implement this on the front-end with JavaScript, (I don't think HTML has a way to define a maximum for multi-selects.) But it's obviously not very dynamic unless you're willing to target `<select>` by name, or apply the limitation to all of them.

As for back-end validation, you could always create an event observer and listen to `sales_quote_product_add_after` and remove the product from the cart, send an error to the session and redirect back the product page if they select too many values. (There isn't a `sales_quote_product_add_before` as far as I'm aware, which is annoying.)